# How do you track trends in software testing?

Tags: quality-assurance, qa-developer

How do you track trends in the industry? Do you use any tooling for this?

Comment: I think this question will not be accepted well here, since it could fall into opinion-based category. However, you can still improve it at least a bit by writing what you do to find out trends in SW testing industry etc. Many opinion-based questions have survived on this site, perhaps you'll be lucky :)

Comment: Have you looked at Practitest survey results? https://qablog.practitest.com/state-of-testing/

Answer (score 2):

I don't use any tooling for this, just a combination of the following:

- reading testing materials (blogs, books, ...)
- reading job ads for testing positions
- participating in testing communities (locally in my country, here)
- following some other testers on LinkedIn and reading what they share about testing
- reading (and learning) about what devs, devops, ... people use, because that affects (if not now, then in the future) my job as well